# Python IDLE game won't run and shows SHELL: RESTART message

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

When I run it, it says:

```
===============RESTART: Volumes/NONAME/myuser/finalProject.py===============

===============================RESTART: Shell===============================
```

and it just won't run.

This is the code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import math
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from pygame.locals import *
from Platform import Platform
from Player import Player
from Coin import Coin
from fireBall import fireBall
import time

pygame.init()
main_clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 460))
background = pygame.image.load('Images/cave.png')
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
pygame.display.set_caption('Ninja Cave Escape')
screen.blit(background, background.get_rect())
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 36)

rndIntx = random.randint(1, 340)
rndInty = random.randint(1, 460)

x = 50
y = 50
speed = 5

lives = 10
score = 0


move_right = False
move_left = False

start = False
gameOver = False

def draw_text(display_string, font, surface, x, y, color):
    text_display = font.render(display_string, 1, color)
    text_rect = text_display.get_rect()
    text_rect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(text_display, text_rect)

    jump_state = 0
    jump_timer = 0
    grounded = False
    hasCollided = False
    time1 = timer()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                if jump_state == 0 and grounded:
                    jump_state = 1
            if event.key == K_RETURN:
                if start:
                    gameOver = False
                    start = False
                else:
                    start = True
            if event.key == K_a:
                move_left = True
                move_right = False
            if event.key == K_d:
                move_left = False
                move_right = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_a:
                move_left = False
            if event.key == K_d:
                move_right = False

    if not start:
        platforms = pygame.sprite.Group()
        platforms1 = []
        platformS = Platform(100, 350, 250, 25)
        platforms.add(platformS)
        platforms1.append(platformS.rect)
        platform1 = Platform(200, 200, 250, 25)
        platforms.add(platform1)
        platforms1.append(platform1.rect)
        platform2 = Platform(300, 280, 250, 25)
        platforms.add(platform2)
        platforms1.append(platform2.rect)
        platform3 = Platform(500, 420, 250, 25)
        platform3.image = pygame.image.load('Images/lava.png').convert_alpha()
        platforms.add(platform3)
        platforms1.append(platform3.rect)
        platform4 = Platform(600, 350, 250, 25)
        platforms.add(platform4)
        platforms1.append(platform4.rect)
        platform5 = Platform(640, 250, 250, 25)
        platforms.add(platform5)
        platforms1.append(platform5.rect)

        coins = []
        coin_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        coin1 = Coin(200, 250)
        coin_group.add(coin1)
        coins.append(coin1.rect)
        coin2 = Coin(400, 200)
        coin_group.add(coin2)
        coins.append(coin2.rect)
        coin3 = Coin(350, 400)
        coin_group.add(coin3)
        coins.append(coin3.rect)

        fBalls_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        fBalls1 = fireBall(640, 110)
        fBalls_group.add(fBalls1)
        fBalls3 = fireBall(640, 280)
        fBalls_group.add(fBalls3)

        player = Player(x, y)

        draw_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        draw_group.add(platformS)
        draw_group.add(platform1)
        draw_group.add(platform2)
        draw_group.add(platform3)
        draw_group.add(platform4)
        draw_group.add(platform5)
        draw_group.add(player)
        gameOver = False
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        player.rect.x = 50
        player.rect.y = 50
        x = 50
        y = 50
        speed = 5

        lives = 10
        score = 0
        timer()

        move_right = False
        move_left = False

        start = False
        gameOver = False
        jump_state = 0
        jump_timer = 0
        grounded = False
        hasCollided = False
        draw_text('Welcome to Ninja Cave Escape!', font, screen, 150, 20,  (255, 0, 0))
        draw_text('If you touch the lava, you will lose a life', font, screen, 100, 80, (0, 255, 0))
        draw_text('If the fireball hits you, you lose a life', font, screen, 100, 150, (0, 255, 0))
        draw_text('Collect Coins to score! And your ninja can also', font, screen, 10, 220, (0, 0, 255))
        draw_text('climb onto platforms by pressing SPACE under them', font, screen, 10, 250, (0, 0, 255))
        draw_text('then pressing SPACE again to go on top.', font, screen, 30, 280, (0, 0, 255))
        draw_text('You can press ENTER any time in the game to restart', font, screen, 10, 310, (0, 0, 255))
        draw_text('Press ENTER to start', font, screen, 200, 410, (0,0,0))
    elif start == True and not gameOver:
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(background, background.get_rect())
        #print(time.time())
        timeString = "%.2f" % round(timer(), 2)
        #if timeString[-2:] == '00' or timeString[-2:]== '01':
            #score += 1
        draw_text('Time Elapsed: ' + timeString, font, screen, 400, 10, (255,255,255))
        draw_text('Score: ' + str(score), font, screen, 10, 10, (255,255,255))
        draw_text('Lives: ' + str(lives), font, screen, 10, 40, (255,255,255))
        if move_left:   
            player.rect.x -= speed
        if move_right:
            player.rect.x += speed
        #if score > 100 and len(coin_group) == 2:
     #       coin_group.add(coin1)
        for coin in coin_group:
            if player.rect.colliderect(coin.rect):
                score += 100
                coin_group.remove(coin)

        main_clock.tick(50)
        if player.rect.colliderect(platform3.rect):
            if not hasCollided:
                lives -= 1
                hasCollided = True
        else:
            hasCollided = False

        if player.rect.y > 480:
            gameOver = True
        if player.rect.x < -5:
            gameOver = True

        if lives <= 0:
            gameOver = True

        if grounded and platforms1[player.rect.collidelist(platforms1)].top - 13 >= player.rect.y:
            y = platforms1[player.rect.collidelist(platforms1)].top - 13

        if jump_state == 0:
            if jump_timer == 0:
                if player.rect.collidelist(platforms1) >= 0:
                    grounded = True
                else:
                    grounded = False
                    y += 7
        elif jump_state == 1:
            jump_timer += main_clock.get_time()
            grounded = False
            y -= 7
            if jump_timer >= 200:
                jump_state = 2
        elif jump_state == 2:
            jump_timer = 0
            jump_state = 0

        platforms.draw(screen)
        draw_group.draw(screen)
        coin_group.draw(screen)
        fBalls_group.draw(screen)
        #red = random.randint(0, 3)
  #     i = 0

        for ball in fBalls_group:
            if player.rect.colliderect(ball.rect):
                if not ball.hasDamaged:
                    lives -= 1
                    ball.hasDamaged = True
                    ball.rect.x = 0
            ball.rect.x -= 1
            if ball.rect.x == -20:
                ball.rect.x = 640
                ball.rect.y = random.randint(1, 460)
                ball.hasDamaged = False

        for coin in coins:
            if coin.x <= 0 - 250:
                #draw_group.add(coin)
                coin.x = 640
                rndInty = random.randint(1, 460)
                rndIntx = random.randint(1, 640)
                coin.y = rndInty
                coin.x = rndIntx
                continue
            else:
                coin.x -= 5
                continue

        for platform in platforms:
            if platform.rect.x <= 0 - 250:
                coin_group.add(coin1)
                coin_group.add(coin2)
         #      if i == red:
         #          i += 1
        #       platform.image = pygame.image.load('Images/lava.png').convert_alpha()
       #    else:
       #        platform.image = pygame.image.load('Images/stonePlatform.png').convert_alpha()
                platform.rect.x = 640
                rndInty = random.randint(1, 460)
                platform.rect.y = rndInty
                continue
            else:
                platform.rect.x -= 5
                continue


        #sprite_rect = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, platforms).rect
        player.rect.y = y - 62
    elif gameOver:
        draw_text('GAME OVER', font, screen, 210, 210, (0,0,0))
        draw_text('Press ENTER to try again', font, screen, 190, 230, (0,0,0))

    pygame.display.update()
```

I can run a simple guessing game in the Python Shell thing, but whenever I run a game, and it appears in a separate window which I made, this error shows up. I made another game and the same error showed up, but I put the code in just in case.

Any help appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: The first restart line says that IDLE started to run your code in the file listed.  The second restart line says that IDLE lost contact with the process running your code and started a new subprocess.  This like means that your code crashed the process.  If you start from a console with, `python3 -m idlelib` or `python2 -m idlelib.idle`, you *might* be lucky and see a traceback or other helpful message in the console.  Also, try running in the console directly, without IDLE.  Change directory to myuser and run `python3 finalProject.py`.  (I am guessing `python3` is used on osx)

Comment: I believe people have run pygame with IDLE>  When I searched SO for `[python-idle] pygame` at least some problems were not about IDLE as such.  If the program always crashes with no clue, comment out large chunk until it runs.

Comment: So by console do you mean terminal? So, should I put it in the terminal, press enter then try run the code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I use python 2, could that be the problem?

Comment: By console, I mean what Windows call Command Prompt -- A window that displays a prompt, such as `somepath>`, where the user enters a command.  So in the Mac console/terminal program, enter the Python 2 version of what I suggested above.  You will not see the RESTART lines as they are specific to IDLE.

Comment: I know someone who has been using pygame in a Windows Python3 program run from IDLE editors for a couple of yours.  (The program has been edited over than period.)  So try without IDLE.  The try much shorter programs (such as minimal 10 lines to display your background) either without or with IDLE depending on the result of the first experiment.

Comment: I tried to launch idle by terminal and entered the command you said, still saw the restart lines for some reason.

Comment: If you ran IDLE, you should still see the Restart lines.  The question was whether you would see an error message in the terminal.  Apparently not.  Not run in the terminal,  without IDLE, as I already suggested.

Comment: To debug such problems, follow the advice in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to find a minimal program that misbehaves.